# What dependencies listed by z3c.dependencychecker should I must not include in my package?

Tags: plone, setuptools, zope

I'm using [z3c.dependencychecker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.dependencychecker) as a helper tool to list the dependencies of my Plone packages.

Someone told me the other day that I should not include all of them because some, like OFS and Products.Five, are special packages included in [Zope 2](http://zope2.zope.org/).

Does anybody has a complete list of these exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zope2 egg distribution contains a number of top-level packages. As of Zope2 2.13.19 these are:

- App
- Globals
- HelpSys
- Lifetime
- OFS
- Products (a namespace package also used by addons)
- Shared
- Signals
- Testing
- ZPublisher
- ZServer
- ZTUtils
- Zope2
- reStructuredText
- webdav

It also contains these packages in the Products namespace:

- Products.Five
- Products.PageTemplates
- Products.Sessions
- Products.SiteAccess
- Products.SiteErrorLog
- Products.TemporaryFolder
- Products.Transience
- Products.ZODBMountPoint
- Products.ZReST

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with the [versions.cfg file for Plone](http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3-latest/versions.cfg), which includes links to the Zope version files.

Note that there is a comment "# Ecosystem (not officially part of core)" part way through the file. Packages listed after that point are not Plone dependencies.